# How do teachers ask to calculate expressions?

Tags: expressions, questions, word-usage

How do American/British primary school teachers ask their pupils to calculate an expression? E.g.

- What is 2+3 equal to?
- What is the value of 2+3?
- ...

In particular, I'm interested whether the first form ("equal to") would ever be used in a primary school.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a third grade teacher in the US (in the 1970s), I variably would asked

> What is 2 + 3?
>   How much is 2 + 3?
>   Add 2 + 3. How much?
>   2 + 3 is what?
>   What does 2 + 3 *equal*?
>   2 + 3 *equals* what?

I probably tended toward the more colloquial, but the term *equal* was definitely part of the vocabulary.

SUPPLEMENT: Formulas were also routinely used on the chalkboard and on worksheets

> 2 + 3 = 5

When read by the students, the = sign was almost always referred to as *equals* not *is*.

Answer (score 2):

When I was at school (certainly at primary school) the question would be asked, "What is two plus three?", however, teaching methods have certainly changed since then. That said, the teacher/pupil may very well answer "two plus three equals five" as well as "two plus three is five"

Answer (score 0):

I think my teachers mostly said, "What is two plus three?", "How many is two plus three?", or "What does two plus three equal?"

Answer (score 0):

My teachers mostly said, "What is two plus three?"

All the other suggestions are possible, but this one, in my humble opinion, is the most common.

Also a bald "2 plus 3?" or "six eights?"